# Rearrange forumla to isolate 1/A

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to rearrange this formula : 
$$A.(B1 + B2) = xYZ $$
to this one : 
$$ 1 / A = [expression 1]B1 +[expression 2]$$
Where **[expression 1]** and **[expression 2]** could contains one or plus from **x, Y, Z or B2**

I tried multiple times without success. If anyone could help me with it or give some sort of hint, it would be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a\cdot (b_1 + b_2) = xyz \implies \frac{1}{xyz}\cdot a \cdot (b_1+b_2)=1\implies \frac 1a =\frac{1}{xyz}b_1+\frac{b_2}{xyz}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, It helped !